# Org-mode -- Summing effort at multiple levels of hierarchy in column view

Tags: org-mode

I have a tree of tasks in org-mode which has effort estimates at multiple levels within a subtree.  In order words, a task may have sub-tasks with their own effort estimates, but the parent task also has an effort estimate which reflects work on the parent task that isn't included in any sub-task.  I want to avoid sticking an "other" or "misc" subtask on each tree just to capture this sort of thing.  The problem is that column view wipes out the effort property on the parent tasks as it percolates up the tree and replaces it with the sum of the child tasks.  This seems like a terrible idea to me -- is there a way to prevent that, or must I push all effort estimates into leaf nodes exclusively?

Comment: The funny thing is that I would like to achieve exactly what you're observing: how did you sum up your efforts in the parent task?

Comment: @tharibo, you must add `{:}` to the column type, e.g. `#+COLUMNS: %70ITEM(Task) %Effort{:}`, see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

As org version 9.2.5 if in the `COLUMNS` declaration we include both `%Effort` and `%Effort(Effort Children){:}~, the effort in the parent node doesn't get overridden when using`M-x org-columns`.

Example

```
#+COLUMNS: %50ITEM TODO %3PRIORITY %Effort %Effort(Effort Children){:} %10CLOCKSUM
```